# Import file names by date taken not by file name with my Excel macro

Tags: vba, excel, rename, batch-rename

I have a excel macro that imports all the files from a folder that I choose and than puts it into a sheet and I would like to import them by date taken (because the files are pictures) not by file name so that the pictures are put in order like this

```
002_1.jpg (time is 7:00am)
001_1.jpg (time is 7:01am)
003_1.jpg (time is 7:03am)
```

see how the files are put in order of when they were taken regardless of the file name.
do you have any ideas how i could modify my current macro to do that?

```
Sub filegrabber()
Dim par, sfil As String
Dim r As Range
par = Application.InputBox("Enter The Directory Dont forget to add the \")
sfil = Dir(par & "*.*", vbDirectory)
Set r = ActiveCell
Do Until sfil = ""
If sfil = "." Or sfil = ".." Then GoTo skipit
r = sfil
ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add r, par & sfil
Set r = r.Offset(1)
skipit:
sfil = Dir$
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't tune the `Dir` for a specific way of looping. So you'd have to get the file's date and then sort your array, so I'd suggest that you use an FSO (File Scripting Object) : http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/filesystemobject-in-vba/ and https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/aa711216(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Why not simply sort the list by date after you have obtained all the file paths?

Answer (score 0):

Use the FileSystemObject to check the date of the file before adding it to your sheet.

```
Dim FileDirectory, FileName As String
Dim r As Range
Dim FindThisDate As Date

Sub filegrabber()
    FileDirectory = Application.InputBox("Enter The Directory Dont forget to add the \")
enterdate:
    FindThisDate = Application.InputBox("Enter The Date of files you want to load")
    If Not IsDate(FindThisDate) Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter A Valid Date", vbCritical, "Invalid Date"
        GoTo enterdate
     Else
        FindThisDate = CDate(FindThisDate)
    End If
    FileName = Dir(FileDirectory & "*.*", vbNormal) 'changed this from vbdirectory cuz you want files, not folders
    Set r = ActiveCell
    While FileName <> ""
        If filedate(FileDirectory & FileName) = FindThisDate Then
            r = FileName
            ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add r, FileDirectory & FileName
            Set r = r.Offset(1)
        End If
        FileName = Dir$
    Wend
End Sub

Function filedate(FileName) As Date
Dim fso, f
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set f = fso.GetFile(FileName)
   filedate = DateValue(f.DateCreated)
   Set fso = Nothing
   Set f = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: what is the date format that it need to give it when it asks "Enter The Date of files you want to load"

Comment: depends on your regional settings, i use English (United States) so it m/d/yyyy (you can actually just use m/d if the year is current year)

Comment: I updated the answer to make sure FindThisDate is a date before comparing